# what is in build method to switch to iframe in Protractor?

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor, ui-automation

For Selenium for switching to iframes has in build method

`WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, defaultWaitPeriod);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(id));`

What is code for the Protractor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do have something like that for protractor

```
browser.switchTo().frame(element(by.tagName('iframe')).getWebElement());
```

For more details you could check the protractor official documentation in the link pasted below

http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.switchTo

Comment: Can you explain me where i will get the element of the frame. i have tried with right click on frame and view frame source. but not got any tag,id etc there.
By using the index or name will throw the error as above code is for only for web element.
.

Comment: Also my code is working with passing index by giving browser.switchTo().frame(0);
But I have to apply browser.sleep() for that and I want to avoid  sleep

Comment: Answer to Question 1: I really cannot comment on it without knowing anything about your source code.

Comment: Answer to Question : Could you please try with something very simple, like wait for an element to visible and  keep it inside a promise  element.isVisible().then(function({ code to switch to frame });